# SQL sort failing when sorted column contains both numeric and alphanumeric values

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm attempting to sort by a field with may contain either numbers, or a letter followed by a number. (But not a mix of both).

My Sort ascending field is

```
 sField: IIf(Val([AlbumTrack]) > 0, CInt([AlbumTrack]), [AlbumTrack])
```

But numbers are not sorting correctly. Letter and numbers seem to be. What am I doing wrong ?

Examples of data are 7,8,9,10,11  A3, A4, A5, B1, B2, C1

My sql is

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW 
    CDTracks.AlbumCat, CDTracks.AlbumTrack, 
    IIf(Val([AlbumTrack])>0,CInt([AlbumTrack]),[AlbumTrack]) AS sField
FROM 
    CDTracks
WHERE 
    (((CDTracks.AlbumCat) = "RCA Victor LSP 2525"))
ORDER BY 
    IIf(Val([AlbumTrack]) > 0, CInt([AlbumTrack]), [AlbumTrack]);
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show examples of the data in your input column and how you would like the sorted output to look. Do you want the sort order to simply ignore the letter at the beginning of the field (if there is one)?

Comment: No, the letter is needed, if present.  Hope the examples help.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, I see what you mean. The issue appears to be that the expression in your ORDER BY clause does not have a consistent data type: for some rows it evaluates to an Integer and for other rows it evaluates to a String.

The following worked for me because the expression in this ORDER BY clause always returns a String:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCTROW
    CDTracks.AlbumCat, CDTracks.AlbumTrack
FROM 
    CDTracks
WHERE 
    (((CDTracks.AlbumCat) = "RCA Victor LSP 2525"))
ORDER BY 
    IIf(Val([AlbumTrack]) > 0, Right("00000" & [AlbumTrack], 5), [AlbumTrack]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, this query shold return rows in the order that you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW 
    CDTracks.AlbumCat, CDTracks.AlbumTrack
FROM 
    CDTracks
WHERE 
    CDTracks.AlbumCat = "RCA Victor LSP 2525"
ORDER BY
  IIf(Val([AlbumTrack]) > 0, Null, Left([AlbumTrack], 1)),
  IIf(Val([AlbumTrack]) > 0, CInt([AlbumTrack]), CInt(MID([AlbumTrack], 2)));
```

This will split the AlbumTrack column in two different columns: one for the alphanumeric part if present, one for the numeric part.

Comment: This also worked perfectly but I couldn't add Nz() as in @Gord Thompson solution without getting an error. The field should never be empty but just in case..